# What's the best Python 3D engine?

Tags: 3d, python

I want a straight 3d Python engine that's easily obtainable for linux and easy to use. Soya3D failed for me because of the lack of documentation. I should be able to load common 3D models without an issue.

Comment: Define 'best'. Do you mean easy to use, well documented, fastest, tidiest API? Or all of them? And your title says 3D, yet you then say 2D/3D. Which?

Comment: Well documented would be the ideal 'best' engine for what i am looking for.
When i say 2d/3d i mean linke in soya3d it uses features from pygame in its syntax. I want a 3d Engine though.

Comment: Whooo! Closed as not constructive but has brought over 10k views to this page (in return to this site).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Panda3D](http://panda3d.org/) is only other one I would really call an engine per se. There are Python bindings for Ogre, but I've heard mixed review of them. Unity can be scripted in Boo which is almost, but not quite, entirely unlike Python.

Answer (score 4):

You can try Panda3D, but this is more a game engine than a 3D engine.

I don't know any 3D engine using python as a main language, since 3D applications are, most of the time, required to have smooth execution speed.

I didn't tried PyOgre either, but you might want to check out PyGLet, I don't really know what it is, but it looks great.

Comment: pyglet's documentation is awful

Comment: PyGlet is not an engine; it is an opengl framework.

Comment: Oh boy, I was soooo wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I love panda3d myself. super easy and well supported. Cross platform and whatnot.

Here's something I made with it:

http://code.google.com/p/stableorbit

Answer (score 3):

I have used pyOgre sometimes and it have a lot of documentation and the community is great. You should give it a try.

I can't say any other thing because i have never used Panda3D

Comment: You really want python-ogre (http://www.python-ogre.org/) instead of the older PyOgre. Other than that, I heartily second the recommendation: python-ogre is flexible, capable and mature.